# What is the proper pronunciation of ומפז?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, tehilim-psalms

Tehilim 19 which is said Shabbos morning at Shacharis has the following Posuk הנחמדים מזהב ומפז רב. I have seen Artscroll Sedurim with a Patach under the Pei of UmiPaz and I have seen Artscroll Sedurim with a Kometz under the Pei of UmiPuz. What is the correct pronunciation?

Comment: Can you check the publication dates in the Siddurim? Could it be that the one is a typo which was later corrected?

Answer (score 7):

According to the Leningrad Codex, it's a Patach.  The Aleppo Codex (Keter Aram Zova) does not have this perek.

A huge PDF of the codex is available at http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Leningrad-codex-15-psalms.pdf.

Both the Koren and Mossad HaRav Kook (Breuer) editions have it with a Patach.  Notably, neither indicates a variant reading of that word in their appendices.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50258&pgnum=367